# CSS safe area attributes doesn't work on iPhone X

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, iphone-x

In my case I'm running a web app on iPhone X, I'm trying to add a padding on top to push my body to the safe area using the safe area css attributes of Webkit `padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);` and `padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);`. However the web view doesn't evaluate correctly these attributes and it's always set to 0.
What should I dod to make it work !
code :

```
body {
padding-top: 44px;
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: add viewport meta with viewport-fit=cover

Answer (score 34):

it needs

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

in the head section of your HTML

Comment: In my case, my meta tag which I grabbed from developer.mozilla (top hit on google) was missing the viewport-fit=cover which seems to be the important bit.

Comment: In my case change the order of value of content in meta tag fix the issue. place viewport-fit=cover as first value of content. <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: This is not working for me in iOS 14.5 or 16.4 simulators. Still `0px`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `safe-area-inset-dir` is undefined on Chrome and Safari on mac, where I suspect you're measuring the padding. To my knowledge, you'll have to load the site on an iOS 11 device in Safari to see this variable have any value. I suspect this is why you have the `0px` padding issue.

Also, as of iOS 11.2, the keyword to use is `env`. In fact, the [iPhone X design guidelines](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/) references this and even includes a nice full example for detecting support for it:

```
@supports(padding: max(0px)) {
    .post {
        padding-left: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-left));
        padding-right: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-right));
    }
}
```

This pattern will do a few things for you:

- Since `max` is not part of standard CSS, we know that we're on Safari / Webkit, where `safe-area-inset-dir` should be defined (where `dir` is a direction).
- Also this will set the padding of the element to either your desired 'normal' padding (`12px` in this case) on most devices or the needed safe area space if you're on an iPhone X. This is because iOS 11 on the iPhone 8 will define this variable as `0`, which would result in padding of `0px` otherwise.

Comment: It seems `min()` and `max()` will become standard CSS functions soon. So in near future this rule might target even other devices/browser than iPhone X. See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-notation.

Comment: Good job looking out, thanks for that info! Apple will probably revise the blog post I linked in the future (as should we this answer) to detect `env` instead of `max` in `@supports`, if I had to guess. When this day comes, I'm not sure how this code will behave when the `@supports` resolves true but `env` is undefined in browsers like Chrome, Firefox. We may be able to have `padding-left: 12px;` and `padding-left: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-left));` on the following line and just have Chrome mark the rule invalid and default to `12px` as a side effect.

Comment: Great! Adding that fallback line would be safer. Although it is still not the time, it would be future proof => I will rather add it in my code now :)

Comment: Does this whole code snippit go inside of the body {} rule set? I'm not familiar with the use of @ in a css file.

Answer (score 3):

This will work like a charm for ionic v3 (or less):

Add this to your index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

then in yout global.scss

```
.ion-app {
  --safe-area-inset-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
  --safe-area-inset-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
  height: calc(100% + (var(--safe-area-inset-top) + var(--safe-area-inset-bottom)));
}
```

in ionic v4 and later seems that this issue is already fix.

Answer (score 0):

without the line
padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
/* safe area in ios and android handled */
body {
  --ion-safe-area-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
  --ion-safe-area-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

this works for me