# Status bar overlays webview on iOS with Capacitor

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ios-statusbar

I would like to achieve the same behavior of statusbar as in the capacitor example, i.e. automatically add the correct padding so my app content doesn't display inside the status bar.
However, I don't use the ionic framework but angular and the status bar overlays the webview of my application. Therefore, the content of my app is visible in the status bar.

I was expecting a method that allows to change this behavior (as the _ overlaysWebView_ method of ionic native status bar).
I also tried to add `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />` in the *config.xml* file but I don't know if I should install the cordova statusbar plugin or not.

Maybe I shouldn't change this configuration and just play with padding, but then I don't know how to handle the different status bar height on different iOS devices.

I'm new to Capacitor and I never used Ionic nor Cordova. I someone could help me deal with this problem, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this issue on some applications I have worked on in the past ond only recently found a clean, less hacky way of fixing it. You will have to add the `safe-area-inset-*` where `*` can be `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom`. This accounts for where the notch position will be when the device is either in portrait or landscape mode.

You can learn more about this by looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47895315/4687451

Comment: Yes you can use safe-area-inset-top to force the top of the browser to show extra padding. But this doesn't necessarily work right if the colors of your header don't match the dark or light theme in use because you're effectively still underflowing. 

Unfortunately for me too this was the only - imperfect - solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the padding of your  directly in your css code thanks to the `env` variables. It works only on iOS so it can be applied on any tag you need.

```
body{
  padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by adding following line in CAPViewBridgeController file

```
webView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)

webView?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Search for below function and update. The function should look like this

```
extension CAPBridgeViewController: CAPBridgeDelegate {
    internal var bridgedWebView: WKWebView? {
        webView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)
        webView?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height;
        return webView
    }

    internal var bridgedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CapacitorJs makes the WebView fill the whole device screen which makes your web content layout underneath the toolbar. This issue still happened for iOS 16.1.2 / Capacitor 4.7.1.

One way to fix this is by adding a top padding or top margin to your SPA to push your content away from the toolbar. Add this to your index.html:

```
  <head>
      <!-- Set viewport-fit to cover, this enables `env(safe-are-insect-*)` variables -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
  </head>
  <!-- 
      Then use the `env(safe-area-insect-*)` variables 
      to push your content away from the toolbar
      how to do it depends on how you layout your app.
      This is just an example. 
  -->
  <body style="padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
```

Comment: Works as long as you don't have a `fixed` header (as I do). In that case the header needs the extra padding, plus the extra margin to push the main content down all adjusted by the safe-area-inset-top offset.